# How to add PDF file to Database

Tags: php, mysql

How to add PDF file in phpmyadmin using php and retrieving it back and display it on webpage ??

Answer (score 3):

That is not so good idea. The better solution will be to upload PDF file to the server,get file path and insert the path of the file in the database and then retrieve that path from a database.

Comment: Correct solution